# How can I rewrite this URL using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How can i rewrite this:
https://www.example.com/post.php?post=1467635139

To this:
https://www.example.com/post/1467635139

Comment: Please search the site because this has been asked and answered already before several times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Although this kind of question is answered before on this site but for your specific url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)([\d]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```